# Behavior of geometric fibers under strict transforms

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, birational-geometry

Consider a digram of the form
$$
\begin{array}{ccc}
 Z' & \rightarrow & Z \\
 \downarrow & & \downarrow \\
 X' & \rightarrow & X \\
 \downarrow & & \downarrow \\
 S' & \rightarrow & S,
\end{array}
$$
where $S$ is a scheme, $S' \to S$ is a blow-up, $X \to S$ is a scheme morphism, $X' \to S'$ is its strict transform (see https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/080C), $Z$ is a constructible locally closed subscheme of $X$ and $Z'$ is its preimage in $X'$.

Assuming that $Z \to S$ has geometric fibers that are either connected or empty, under what assumptions can I say the same for the geometric fibers of $Z' \to S'$?

In my special situation all schemes are noetherian, $S$, $S'$, $X$ and $Z$ are normal and $X \to S$ is also a blow-up (in case that helps...).